# How can I get the Oauth Access Token when using play-authenticate?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am using play-authenticate to login a user with Google Oauth2.  Now I want to get the Access Token so I can use some Google APIs.

Can anyone help me out here?  Is it so obvious that I am missing how to do it?

I can get a User like this (from the examples):

```
final AuthUser u = PlayAuthenticate.getUser(session());
```

But what I really need is the

```
OAuth2AuthUser.getOAuth2AuthInfo().getAccessToken()
```

I can't cast the `AuthUser` as an `OAuth2AuthUser`.  so how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

We came up with a solution that overrides the update method of our UserServicePlugin. Just create a class that derives from com.feth.play.module.pa.service.UserServicePlugin, and register that class as plugin in your play.plugins file (as you might have already done when you're using play-authenticate).

Then, in the overridden update method, you can store the access token as you like.

```java
@Override
public AuthUser update(final AuthUser knownUser)
{
    if (knownUser instanceof OAuth2AuthUser)
    {
        OAuth2AuthUser oAuth2AuthUser = (OAuth2AuthUser) knownUser;
        String oauth2accessToken = oAuth2AuthUser.getOAuth2AuthInfo().getAccessToken();
        Context.current().session().put("oauth2accessToken", oauth2accessToken);
    }

    return knownUser;
}
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/samples/java/Getting%20Started.md) says that's the method that's "called when a user logs in. You might make profile updates here with data coming from the login provider or bump a last-logged-in date."

In fact, calling Authenticate.authenticate (as you do from your routes) calls, in order, PlayAuthenticate.handleAuthentication, PlayAuthenticate.loginAndRedirect, PlayAuthenticate.storeUser and finally update of the current user service plugin.